# CSS, overwrite height of all select dropdowns?

Tags: html, css

how would i reference, so i could overwrite, all of the select boxes so i can overwrite the default height? I'm familiar when i create elements using a class, but im unsure on this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

100% JS solution (with jquery)

```
$("select").height("120px");
```

100% JS solution (without jquery)

```
var selects = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
for(i = 0;i < selects.length; i++) {
    selects[i].style.height = "120px";
}
```

100% CSS solution

```
select {
    height: 100px !important;
}
```

Comment: `!important` overrides all, and defeats the meaning of 'default' as the asker said.

Answer (score 2):

You mean the menu that pops up when dropping down a native `select` element?

I don't think you can influence that at all, that's entirely up to the browser.

What you might be able to influence - it should work in all current browsers - is the `select` itself:

```
select { height: .... }
```

or each option (Should work in Firefox; spotty support otherwise)

```
select option { height: .... }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
select { height: 60px; }
```

Replace `60` with your desired height.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select {height:100px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

100 % work in my scenerio ..

```
<select onfocus='this.size=10;' onblur='this.size=1;' 
        onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();'>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to give a class on your select element. `<select name="nameforyourselect" class="myclass"></select>`

Then on your css set the height, for example `.myclass{height:30px;}` this will give height 30px on all elements with class name myclass. I suggest you this way, because you may wish to create another select element with another height. So you just set other class on it and define it on your css.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily do this using css use line-height and font-size.

```
select {
    line-height: 1em;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```