# Limit dropdown visible items

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, struts2

I have a dropdown like below.

```
<s:select list="myList" listValue="name" listKey="myId"
                emptyOption="true" 
                    name="pkg.nameId" 
                    id="nameId" />
```

I would like to limist the visible list of dropdown to 6. 
I get the list size using the below

```
<s:property value ="myList.size()"/>
```

Not sure how to limit the visible items though. Any leads ?

Comment: You mean like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476314/css-overwrite-height-of-all-select-dropdowns

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `size` attribute:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_size.asp

Please note, however, that it also changes the appearance of the select list.

If you need the appearance to stay the same, you should use CSS/JS to set the height, as suggested in this answer (from `25r43q`'s comment):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3476355/1819335

Comment: Yeah appearance changes. But I wanna do it as how dropdown looks.

Comment: In that case, you should use CSS to set the height, as @25r43q pointed out in their comment.