# Select list item partially cut off in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-steps

Can someone tell me what might cause Firefox to render the selected item in a select list off center vertically?

[image]

This is happening in CRM using Jquery Steps and Validation.  Not sure if that is a potential source of the issue/css conflict or not.

Select list displays normally in Safari and Chrome.

I am setting the width of the select list in jquery

```
$("#state").css("width", "180px");
```

No other styling is being intentionally applied to it.

Comment: By doing this I was able to work around the issue.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476314/css-overwrite-height-of-all-select-dropdowns

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because there is not enough room. Those drop-down boxesneed a little bit extra room to fit the text in.  It's an easy fix really, just add a bit more height to the css.